# Is prime ideal equivalent to cannot be factored into 2 proper ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Is prime ideal equivalent to cannot be factored into 2 proper ideals?   Sorry if this is a stupid question I couldn't find this in the list of characterizations for prime ideals on Wikipedia.

Comment: KReiser has given you a counterexample for the general statement, but it is true when we restrict to the case of Dedekind domains (and exclude the $0$ ideal).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not an equivalence. The ideal $(x,y^2)\subset k[x,y]$ for $k$ a field cannot be factored as a product of ideals, but is clearly not prime as $y\cdot y=y^2\in(x,y^2)$ but $y\notin (x,y^2)$. If $I,J$ are two proper ideals so that $IJ=(x,y^2)$ then we must have that $\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{J}=(x,y)$. But $IJ\subset \sqrt{I}\sqrt{J} = (x,y)^2$, so $x\notin IJ$ and $IJ\neq (x,y^2)$.

Comment: ... or as the only way to factor $x$ is $c\cdot c^{-1}x$, one of $I,J$ must contain a unit.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen good alternate argument, I obviously still have my algebraic-geometer hat on.